# $f \le 1 \Rightarrow f =1 $ a.s.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I know the title doesn't say much, but I hope you'll help me nonetheless.

Here's my problem.

Let $P, Q$ be two probabilistic measures, $P$ is atomless and the measures have the same independent events.

Then $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$ (I've already proven that). We can therefore consider Radon-Nikodym's derivative $f = \frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}Q}$

Could you explain to me why this sentence is true?

If $f \le 1$, then $f = 1 $ a.s. $[Q]$? Would this mean that the measures are equal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\lt1$ and $A=\{f\leqslant x\}$, then $f\leqslant x$ on $A$ and $f\leqslant1$ on $\Omega\setminus A$ hence $$1=\displaystyle\int_\Omega\mathrm dP=\int_\Omega f\mathrm dQ\leqslant\int_Ax\cdot\mathrm dQ+\int_{\Omega\setminus A}\mathrm dQ= xQ(A)+1-Q(A).$$ Thus, $(x-1)Q(A)\geqslant0$. Since $x\lt1$, this shows that $Q(A)=0$.

This holds for every $x\lt1$ hence $Q(\{f\lt1\})=0$, that is, $f=1$ $Q$-almost surely.

In particular, $P=Q$ since, for every measurable $B$,
$$
P(B)=\int_Bf\cdot\mathrm dQ=\int_B\mathrm dQ=Q(B).
$$